# To Witness Something of Such Beauty

Tags: adverbs, colloquialisms

There is a word used in English but from Italian (I think) which has the following meaning:

> To witness something or someone of such profound beauty that you are
>   compelled to sing aloud in praise.

I cannot find it anywhere. I remember that, when asked, it sounded a little like the French word "parler" or "parlons" (to speak) if that helps.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [**paean**](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/paean)? That's got something to do with praise and is somewhat close to *parlons* in sound

Comment: If there genuinely *is* a word for this, it'll rival [Shoeburyness](http://www.tickld.com/thread/4280800) as the showcase example demonstrating that English has a word for *everything*.

Answer (score 2):

While not matching your French hint ...

***Rapture*** or ***raptures***. [MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/rapture) says

> to be in an extremely happy or excited state, and show this by what you say

But there are many other possibilities:

- ecstasy
- elation
- euphoria
- exaltation
- exhilaration
- enchantment
- inspiration
- rhapsody
- transports